# Photo & Comment Upload Form And Display In Page

Tags: php, video, upload, webforms, photo

Could somebody please teach me how to:

firstly create a photo and comment upload form and then display the comment and photo on the page?

secondly create a photo, video and comment upload form and then display the photo or video with the comment on a web page?

I am finding this extremely hard to get my head around so please talk to me like a 5 year old!

Thank you

Comment: Not on Stackoverflow. We don't provide lessons but only to help if you have trouble with your code. Sorry for that.

Comment: Ok well could somebody maybe show me the code I need? :)

Comment: You can start with this: 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp